# Reduce superscript font size ggplot2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2, format, markdown, ggtext

I'm developing a script with `ggplot2` and the package `ggtext` to produce some plots with superscripts next to the title that further are grouped in a reference table.

A simplified example of what I'm doing is:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

ggplot() +
geom_blank() +
labs(title = "The title of the plot^21") +
theme_void() +
theme(plot.title = element_markdown(size = 20, hjust = 0.5))
```

But as I need to work with big font sizes in my project, it just happens that the superscript font size is too big. Is there a way to reduce it while keeping the same text size? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this can be helpful:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)
#Code
ggplot() +
  geom_blank() +
  labs(title = "The title of the plot<span style='font-size:20pt;
       color:black'><sup>2</sup></span>") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(plot.title = element_markdown(size = 25, hjust = 0.5))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yes! It actually helped! I found out that doing a double carat "^^" instead of a single also does the job but your solution definitely gives more room to work with.

Comment: @fernandoschuh why not also offering this as an answer to your own question - this way this solution is better visible and will help future generations :) Thanks for your contribution and welcome to Stackoverflow. Nice first question.

Answer (score 0):

Later on I've found out that we can just use a double carat in the code which also answers my question:

```
labs(title = "The title of the plot^^21")
```